# Vaadin Switch component showed as ComboBox

Tags: vaadin

I added a [Vaadin Switch component](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/switch) to my project but it's being showed exactly as a CheckBox. How can I show it as a switch? I have to add a new CSS style or something?

Comment: did you applied some custom theming to that?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm using 2.0.3 version of the Switch component with Vaadin 7.6.2.

Comment: You need to recompile your widgetset. Switch extends CheckBox so right now it's fallbacking to that.

Comment: I have recompiled my widgetset:
`mvn vaadin:update-widgetset;
mvn vaadin:compile`
but it is still showing as a checkbox. I have to do anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not using the new generated widgetset files in the WAR file. I copied them and now it's working.